# How to route the form action to a specific file by using express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using express.router and ejs template. I want the logic of one of my form with a POST method will be handled not in the app file (the main file of the application) but in some other file with the name 'user.js' using router.post. It returns 404 since it's trying to find the logic on the main file instead on the users.js file.

How can I route the post logic to be handled in the user.js file?

**app.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

var router = express.Router();


var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**users file (routes/users.js)**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('../app')
const axios = require('axios');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {User} = require('../models/userModel')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');


const router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("user");
});

router.post('/userSearch', (req, res) =>  {
  res.send(req.body.myUser);
})


module.exports = router;
```

**user file (views/user.ejs)**

```
<h1>Welcome to users page</h1>

<form action="/userSearch" method="POST">
Search user:<input type ="search" name="myUser"></br>
<input type = "submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few unnecessary declarations on your files but the main reason your are not reaching the router path is because you are POSTing to a NOT declared route:

```
<form action="/userSearch" method="POST">
```

should be:

```
 <form action="/users/userSearch" method="POST">
```

#### EXTRA

Few fixes for your files:

**app.js**

```
var router = express.Router(); //not needed here
```

**users file (routes/users.js)**

```
var app = require('../app') //not needed here
```

Comment: Thanks also for the extra :)